# How to sum over an array of variant using a visitor?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, variant

I'm trying to find a way to sum over an `std::array` of `std::variant` using a visitor. I've gotten this far, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to deduce the type of the visitors without including a `void` entry at the head of my visitor lambda list.

Does anyone know of a way I can deduce the return type of the lambdas in the visitor so that I don't have to rely on this?

Here's what I've got right now:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

template<typename... Base>
struct Visitor: Base ... {
    using Base::operator()...;
};

template<typename... T>
Visitor(T...) -> Visitor<T...>;

// There has to be a better way to deduce Result than what I'm doing...
template<typename... T, typename S, typename... Ss, size_t N, typename Result = typename std::result_of_t<S()>>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<Result>, Result>
summation(const Visitor<S, Ss...> &visitor, const std::array<std::variant<T...>, N> &array) {
    Result sum{};
    for (const auto &a: array)
        sum += std::visit(visitor, a);
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    constexpr Visitor visitor {
            // This first entry should be unnecessary, I would think:
            []()                   -> double { return 0; },
            [](double d)           -> double { return d + 3.4; },
            [](int i)              -> double { return i - 2; },
            [](std::string_view s) -> double { return s.size(); }
    };

    constexpr std::array<std::variant<int, double, std::string_view>, 5> arr{9.0, 9, 3, 5.2, "hello world"sv};
    constexpr auto val = summation(visitor, arr);
    std::cout << val << '\n';
}
```

Edit: I'd like the result to be `constexpr`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::accumulate()` ?

Comment: I was thinking of something (which is probably unnecessarily overcomplicated, but I have a bad habit of not seeing the obvious) like this:

`auto val2 = std::accumulate(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr), [&visitor](auto v){return std::visit(visitor, v);});`

but the compiler complains that this isn't `constexpr`, which I would like.

Comment: (Also, I figure this will be an opportunity for me to learn something or two more about template metaprogramming.)

Comment: The compiler complains because you're missing an argument.

Comment: Whoops... a 0 in the third parameter and a binary op as the fourth? I still get that the final expression isn't `constexpr`, and cppreference doesn't seem to indicate that `accumulate` has a `constexpr` version.

Comment: I should have written: `auto val2 = std::accumulate(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr), 0, [&visitor](const auto a, const auto &v){return a + std::visit(visitor, v);});` in my comment, but again, it doesn't seem to yield a `constexpr` result.

Comment: You should use `0.0` for the third  parameter, not `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplification (I hope) of the Frank's `decltype()`/`std::declval()` solution.

Using `decltype()`/`std::declval()`, you don't need to know `S`, `Ss...` and `T...`; you simply need a template type `V` for `visitor` and a template type for `array`.

You can also avoid the `static_assert()`, if you prefer, re-enabling SFINAE simply writing

```
template <typename V, typename A,
          typename R = decltype(std::visit(std::declval<V>(), std::declval<A>().at(0)))>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<R>, R>
   summation(V const & visitor, A const &array)
{
    R sum{};
    for (const auto &a: array)
        sum += std::visit(visitor, a);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: A modification to have `R` as first type to allow easier specification: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6e5fc86f4adb6a8) or even simpler with extra arg: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b795380ddbb29a24).

Comment: @Jarod42 - Not sure to understand... the advantage is that you can call `summation()` explicating the return type (by example: `auto val = summation<long double>(visitor, arr);`), so it's directly called the three-template version, or not explicating it, so it's called the two-template version that deduce the return type and call the three-type version. Correct?

Comment: I initially though that you introduce `R` to allow user provided return type, but it seems you just want to use it for `enable_if`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - yes: I reintroduced `R` for SFINAE purposes, as in OP code, that in Frank's answer is transformed in a `static_assert()` (so the OP and the occasional reader can choose the two ways).

Answer (score 2):

You are being way too explicit with your type infering when `auto` is there to let the compiler take care of that for you.

Once you are within the scope of the function `decltype()` and `std::declval()` make the inference (needed to create the default-initialized target) an easy matter since you can simply mock an actual invocation of the visitor.

```
template<typename... T, typename S, typename... Ss, size_t N>
constexpr auto summation(const Visitor<S, Ss...> &visitor, const std::array<std::variant<T...>, N> &array) {

    using Result = decltype(std::visit(visitor, std::declval<std::variant<T...>>()));
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<Result>);

    Result sum{};
    for (const auto &a: array)
        sum += std::visit(visitor, a);
    return sum;
}
```

I actually much prefer this style since an erroneous invocation will actually yield a sensible error message instead of "function not found". That is unless you will have non-arithmetic versions of `accumulate()` that you are trying to sfinae against (which would be weird).

Comment: Excellent. I had a feeling that `decltype` might solve the problem, but I wasn't sure how, and I need to learn how to use `declval`.

Much appreciated!

Comment: I guess we can get rid of the `typename S` as well.

Comment: Well, you could duck type all the arguments and just go `template<typename VisitT, typename ConatinerT> constexpr auto summation(const VisitT& , const ContainerT& )`, but then you basically have a range-based version of `std::accumulate()`.